# C uint8_t array memory inaccessible in function call

Tags: c, arrays

I have a simple byte array structure:

```
typedef struct ByteArray {
    int size;
    uint8_t* arr;
} ByteArray;
```

that I'm creating like this:

```
ByteArray* byte_array_create(size_t size) {
    ByteArray* a = malloc(sizeof(ByteArray));
    a->size = size;
    a->arr = (uint8_t*)malloc(a->size);
    return a;
}
```

later I'm using this in another module like this:

```
static void rom_set_prg_bank(Rom* r, iNESHeader* h, FILE* romFile) {
    r->PRG = byte_array_create(h->numPRG * 0x4000);
    size_t size = fread(r->PRG->arr, r->PRG->size, 1, romFile);
    byte_array_print(r->PRG->arr);
}
```

now inside of rom_set_prg_bank() r->PRG->arr has it's allocated memory and everything looks good.  I can look through the memory block and see everything.  As soon as I get into byte_array_print() I get a bad access error.

```
void byte_array_print(ByteArray* a) {
    for(int i = 0; i < a->size; i++) {
        // EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) happens 
        // when I try to access any of the values in the
        // byte array
        printf(a->arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That call to print should be `byte_array_print(r->PRG);`. What is your actual code?

Comment: Ah you're right.  I've made that change and now my function is getting the actual ByteArray* struct as it should but I'm still getting a bad access error here: printf(a->arr[i]);

Comment: Ok, its because I wasn't using printf correctly.  It should have been printf("%d", a->arr[i]);

Comment: What does your compiler tell you, when you pass a `uint8_t*` to a function that expects a `ByteArray*`? Did you enable any warnings?

Comment: @Gerhardh That's a good point, I don't know why the compiler didn't complain.  I'll turn on stricter warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte_array_print(r->PRG->arr);
```

passes the allocated buffer defined as an element of the `ByteArray` struct, but `byte_array_print` expects a pointer to the full `ByteArray` struct, not the buffer. Fix it with:

```
byte_array_print(r->PRG)
```